# html5 validation on apex:inputsecret

Tags: visualforce, validation, html5, required, inputsecret

html5 validation fires on all fields except apex:inputsecret field.Any reason behind this ?

```
<apex:page id="Registration" showHeader="false" controller="SiteRegisterController" title="{!$Label.site.register}" docType="html-5.0">
        <br/>
          <center>
                  <apex:outputText> <b>Self Registration</b></apex:outputText>
                      <apex:form id="theForm" forceSSL="true">
                        <apex:pageMessages id="error"/>
                        <apex:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-top:1em;">
                          <apex:outputLabel value="{!$Label.site.username}" for="username"/>
                          <apex:inputText required="true" id="username" value="{!username}" />
                          <apex:outputLabel value="{!$Label.site.community_nickname}" for="communityNickname"/>
                          <apex:inputText required="true" id="communityNickname" value="{!communityNickname}" />
                          <apex:outputLabel value="{!$Label.site.email}" for="email" />
                          <apex:inputText required="true" id="email" value="{!email}" />
                          <apex:outputLabel value="{!$Label.site.password}" for="password"/>
                          <apex:inputSecret id="password" value="{!password}" required="true"/>
                          <apex:outputLabel value="{!$Label.site.confirm_password}" for="confirmPassword"/>
                          <apex:inputSecret id="confirmPassword" value="{!confirmPassword}" required="true"/>
                          <apex:outputText value=""/>
                          <apex:commandButton action="{!registerUser}" value="{!$Label.site.submit}" id="submit"/>
                        </apex:panelGrid> 
                        </apex:form>                  
          </center>
    </apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The required attribute on the `<apex:inputSecret>` does not appear to be passed through to the DOM. Maybe it is used for server side validation only from what I can tell.

the output of the `<apex:inputSecret>` is as follows:

```
<input id="j_id0:j_id1:abc" type="password" name="j_id0:j_id1:abc" value=""/>
```

The markup from the VF page was:

```
<apex:inputSecret required="true" id="abc"/>
```

The only way I was able to allow HTML5 validation was to add JS or jQuery to the document onReady to add the required attribute to all password inputs:

```
$('input[type="password"]').prop('required','true');
```

Once I did that the HTML5 validation worked as expected.